# x-terminal-emulator command and bash OR logic

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Having a strange occurrence with some bash OR logic commands I'm attempting. Usually everything works fine:

```
/bin/bash -c "gnome-terminal || notify-send 'ERROR'"
```

This will try to run gnome-terminal and then only run the second part if the first command fails. For instance if "gnome-terminal" is not installed (or I deliberately change it to "XXXXgnome-terminal" to cause it to fail), it will show the "notify-send" error. But otherwise the second command after the "||" will never run, because the first command succeeded.

But this acts differently:

```
/bin/bash -c "x-terminal-emulator || gnome-terminal || notify-send 'ERROR'"
```

This will bring up a terminal window (called up by `x-terminal-emulator`), then when I close that terminal window it will proceed to the next command and bring up a second terminal window (called up by the `gnome-terminal` part of the logic).

I understand that x-terminal-emulator is a symlink that just points to the default terminal. But it seems to be causing the bash OR logic to believe that it "failed" even when it succeeded.

I've tried a couple of different ways of wrapping the x-terminal-emulator command (like `$(x-terminal-emulator)` or `$(which x-terminal-emulator)`) to get it to more successfully provide the OR logic with a "success" status so the commands after it don't get run. But nothing has worked so far.

Ideas?

The point of the code is to:

1. Try to call the user's default terminal, in case it's different from gnome-terminal.
2. Fall back on just running gnome-terminal, if "x-terminal-emulator" doesn't exist.
3. If that fails, show an error notification.

Is this actually the fault of calling the `x-terminal-emulator` symlink, or is it happening because it's ultimately pointing at `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper` and that isn't emitting a "success" code back to the bash logic?

Edit: OK, it makes the command a lot longer and more complex-looking, but the code below seems to work reliably. It will only bring up a single terminal window, and will call the alternative terminal app if `gnome-terminal` is not set as the default, but fall back to `gnome-terminal` if `x-terminal-emulator` fails. And I should be able to add any number of other alternatives to try:

```
/bin/bash -c "if [[ -x $(type -p x-terminal-emulator) ]]; then x-terminal-emulator; elif [[ -x $(type -p gnome-terminal) ]]; then gnome-terminal; else notify-send 'ERROR: App not found' 'Install a terminal app'; fi"
```

I got it working thanks to the suggestion from @waltinator below. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your command and for me it works as you expected, ie. displays only one gnome-terminal window (no other window after I closed the first one). Also `x-terminal-emulator`, when run alone from command line, returns **immediately** without waiting for terminal window to be closed, so if it will end with a non-zero error code, the second terminal window would appear right after the first one, and not after it is closed.

Comment: Don't try to detect this by executing possibilities, read `man bash` and use `[[ -x $(type -p gnone-terminal) ]]`. You cannot rely on a GUI program to fail reasonably.

Comment: @waltinator You mean replace the "||" logic with with a full if-then-else-fi construct, using this type of test?